# need an empty XML while unmarshalling a JAXB annotated class

Tags: java, jaxb

I have a JAXB annotated class Customer as follows

```
@XmlRootElement(namespace = "http://www.abc.com/customer")
public class Customer{

private String name;
private Address address;


@XmlTransient
private HashSet set = new HashSet<String>();

public String getName(){
return name;
}

@XmlElement(name = "Name", namespace = "http://www.abc.com/customer" )
public void setName(String name){
this.name = name;
set.add("name");
}

public String getAddress(){
return address;
}

@XmlElement(name = "Address", namespace = "http://www.abc.com/customer")
public void setAddress(Address address){
this.address = address;
set.add("address");
}

public HashSet getSet(){
return set;
}
}
```

I need to return an empty XML representing this to the user, so that he may fill the necesary values in the XML and send a request
So what I require is :

```
<Customer>
<Name></Name>
<Address></Address>
</Customer>
```

If i simply create an empty object

```
Customer cust = new Customer() ;
marshaller.marshall(cust,sw);
```

all I get is the toplevel element since the other fields of the class are unset.

What can I do to get such an empty XML? I tried adding the nillable=true annotation to the elements however, this returns me an XML with the xsi:nil="true" which then causes
my unmarshaller to ignore this.

How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Something like `<Name></Name>` represents an empty, non-null String, but your java object is going to be initialized with nulls.  If you want JAXB to marshall empty values, you need to set those values:

```
Customer cust = new Customer() ;
cust.setName("");
cust.setAddress("");
marshaller.marshall(cust, sw);
```

Comment: My class could have members of any data type. If its an integer I will have to initialize to 0, boolean to false etc. 
I am writing a generic program which should give me a blank for all elements irrespective of the data type, and also initialize the complex types and their elements with a blank value. which means I will have to recursively loop through all the elements and their child elements.

Comment: @sswdeveloper: That's true. However, that's the way it works. `<Name></Name>` in XML means a different thing to having no element present. If you want the element present, you have to supply a value.